# Separate array after each second comma

Tags: javascript, arrays

I got an array from a **CMS** that is poorly formatted which I want to reformat to an array of objects.

```
let daysOffArray = ["2022-08-22, 08:00 - 14:00","2022-08-23, 08:00 - 13:00"];
```

Expected result after separating the array:

```
let daysOff = [{
date: "2022-08-22",
time: 08:00 - 14:00
},
{
date: "2022-08-23",
time: 08:00 - 13:00
}];
```

How can I separate the array `daysOffArray` for **each second comma** and then separate the **two new arrays after each comma**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *array destructuring* and the *object literal property value shorthand* for a more concise solution and better readability.

```
daysOffArray.map(item => {
    const [date, time] = item.split(', ');
    return { date, time };
});
```

Comment: Thank you, clean code and easy to read!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
let daysOff = daysOffArray.map(item => {
  const data = item.split(", ");
  return { date: data[0], time: data[1] };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  // Initial object
  var daysOffArray = [
     '2022-08-22, 08:00 - 14:00',
     '2022-08-23, 08:00 - 13:00',
  ];

  // An empty array for the formatted object
  var daysOffFormatted = [];

  // Splitting and formatting the array
  daysOffArray.forEach((daysOff) => {
     var date = daysOff.split(',')[0].trim();
     var time = daysOff.split(',')[1].trim();

     // Adding formatted object to the array

     daysOffFormatted.push({ date, time });
  });

  console.log(daysOffFormatted);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let daysOffArray = ["2022-08-22, 08:00 - 14:00","2022-08-23, 08:00 - 13:00"];

let daysOff = [];

daysOffArray.forEach((item) => {
  daysOff.push({ date: item.split(",")[0], time: item.split(",")[1] });
});

console.log(daysOff);
```

Comment: If you're not using the return value from `map`, you should use `forEach` instead

Answer (score -1):

```js
let daysOff = daysOffArray.map((datetime)=>{
    const [date, time] = datetime.split(',');
    return {date, time: time.trim()};
});
```

Comment: You could just split the string with `, ` as a delimiter instead of just the comma and avoid having to trim the string.